# How to save List with help of JSON?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, game-development

everyone!

Tried to make saver of my List with help of combination JSON and PlayerPrefs but stucked with the problem. It don't save my list and don't load. It only giving me my list with zero elements.

Code:

```
private List<Toggle> _listActiveToggles = new List<Toggle>();

public void Awake()
{
    Load();

    foreach (Toggle toggle in _listActiveToggles)
    {
        toggle.isOn = true;
    }
    
}

public void ChooseUsableBuffs(Toggle toggle)
{
    int level = PlayerPrefs.GetInt("HDD") / 10; 

    if (_listActiveToggles.Any(x => toggle))
    {
        _listActiveToggles.Remove(toggle);
        Debug.Log(_listActiveToggles.Count);
        return;
    }
    
    if (_listActiveToggles.Count >= level)
    {
        _listActiveToggles[0].isOn = false;
        _listActiveToggles.RemoveAt(0);
    }
    _listActiveToggles.Add(toggle);
    Save();
    Debug.Log(_listActiveToggles.Count);
}

public void Save()
{
    PlayerPrefs.SetString("Key" ,JsonUtility.ToJson(_listActiveToggles));
}

public void Load()
{
    _listActiveToggles = JsonUtility.FromJson<List<Toggle>>(PlayerPrefs.GetString("Key"));
}
```

Tried to check what JSON contains and it showed only: **{}**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `JsonUtility` can not directly serialized array and list types.

You rather need a wrapper class like

```
[Serializable]
public class ToggleData
{
    public List<Toggle> _listActiveToggles = new List<Toggle>();
}

public ToggleData data;
```

Which now you can serialize

```
var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(Data);
```

and deserilialize

```
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, data);
```

---

However, in your specific case I guess it will not work anyway. `UnityEngine.UI.Toggle` is of type `MonoBehaviour` and you can not simply deserilialize these from JSON!

You can only store their settings and loading settings into **existing** toggles.

---

I guess actually it should be enough to store a list of `bool` to JSON and iterate over your toggles and the list and do e.g.

```
using System.Linq;

...

[Serializable]
public class ToggleData
{
    public List<bool> ToggleStates = new List<book>();
}

public ToggleData data;

[SerializeField] private List<Toggle> _listActiveToggles = new List<Toggle>();
```

And then save via

```
data.ToggleStates = _listActiveToggles.Select(t => t.isOn).ToList();
var json = JsonUtility.ToJson(Data);
```

and deserilialize via

```
JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(json, data); 
for(var i = 0; i < Mathf.Min(data.ToggleStates.Count, _listActiveToggles.Count); i++)
{
    _listActiveToggles[i].isOn = data.ToggleStates[i];
}
```

Note however that this means you should reference all Toggles you want to save the state for in your list via the Inspector and can not simply remove or add entries on  runtime!